# Optimal Way to Partition 1tb drive

Tags: partitioning

I learned that it is best to store applications in c drive together with the system files.
Does that mean I should give an extra-large partition for c drive? I am planning to give 400gb out of 1tb for c drive, it that too much?

Or should I leave c drive for system files only and just put every application in d drive.

Comment: Do you play lots of games, or use lots of very large software suites? Generally speaking 256GiB is sufficient for most usecases, especially if they have another disk for storing non-app data. Its the applications and games and basic user info storage that really should guide your decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications and System files on the same logical C partition is a good idea, as you learned. It's the user data that tends to consume most-of-the-space over time. Keeping user data separate has its' advantages, whether for backup, fragmentation, access control, future migration, organization, convenience...

Many current model laptops come with 250GB SSD, such as the popular ThinkPad T470s or Dell XPS15, so 400GB would be roomy for a C partition today. Just checking mine with WinDirStat, I have 600GB user data and 100GB of Applications and System files (Win 10) on one drive. Everyone's mileage varies, of course.

If you are knowledgeable with drive re-partitioning, you can go with your 400GB, and trim it based on your usage pattern. And you may find It's easier to accommodate when the d: partition gets crowded with user data than a restricted c: partition. Plus setting at 400GB you wouldn't be constrained from leaving user data on you c: partition if you wanted to. :)